# Laravel 5.5 - Passing form's Data to Controller then Passing Data from Controller to the same View

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I give up ! 2days i'm looking for solution for my problem. 
All I need is pass FORM Data to Controller, then just show it on the same View.
Easy, right ? But i can not find any solution and Laravel's Manual does not explain that clearly...

So this is my View with the form :

### form.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ action('FormController@ReceiveDataForm') }}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Enter your surname">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


<div class="ShowDataHere">
    {{-- Here i want to show this Data from FORM above, but with using Controller. --}}
</div >
```

My Controller receiving data:

### FormController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class FormController extends Controller

    public function Form()
    {
        return view('test.form');
    }

    public function ReceiveDataForm()
    {
        Input::post('name');
        Input::post('surname');
    }
```

And my question is how to pass this Data to the same View and show it on
user's screen ?
Please note that Data must be basically pushed to the Controller, just then passing to the View via Routing. 

All solution i found in Internet does not work for me, what guys am i doing wrong ?

If you do not know  proper answer, please direct me where to find it or similar.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
    public function ReceiveDataForm(Request $request)
    {
        //Input::post('name');
        //Input::post('surname');

        return view('test.form');
    }
```

Import the `Request` class by adding `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your controller.
In your view

```
    <div class="ShowDataHere">
        @if(!empty(request()->all()))
            {{ request()->name }}
        @endif
    </div >
```

In your web.php file, make sure you have

```
    Route::post('/test', 'FormController@ReceiveDataForm');
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but i receiving then :

Action App\Http\Controllers\FormController@ReceiveDataForm not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kamil-lonowski\kamil-lonowski.dev\resources\views\test\form.blade.php)

Comment: The problem comes from your routes configuration. Let me see the route you use for the post

Comment: route i tried :

Route::post('/test', 'FormController@ReceiveDataForm');

Comment: Thank You for trying, but getting now: 

 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: request (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kamil-lonowski\kamil-lonowski.dev\resources\views\test\form.blade.php)

I have a feeling that all these errors i have already saw, when i was looking for solution during 2 days. What is wrong with Laravel ? It should be easy to do in framework...

Comment: Laravel is great, just that you are new to it and you need good resources to learn it. The answer has been updated again.

Comment: WOOOHAAA IT works ! :)  Thank You so much, i'm learning Laravel all day long, but sometimes i am confused as i heard that Laravel teaching bad practices and have a lot of doubts during coding in Laravel. Thank you again i will analize your answer and going to make up missing info about this method.

Comment: Thanks. Mark the answer to close the question. You can contact me for any help.